# Probability that only one student receives their own textbook

Tags: random-variable

Problem: At the end of an exam, four textbooks are left behind. At the beginning of the next lecture, the four texts are randomly returned to the four students. Let X be the number of students who receive their own book. Obtain the pmf of X.

The answer key for P(x=1) is $\frac{{4 \choose 1} \times 2}{24}$

Why there's a 2 in there? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above problem is solved by couting the number of situations in which exactly one student gets their own book, divided by the number of possible situations.

The number of possible situations is 24 - we can rearrange the four different books in 24 ways ($4!$).

Now suppose we have students A, B, C and D and books $K_a, K_b, K_c, K_d$

If A gets their book, we need to split $K_b, K_c, K_d$ by the remaining students in a way in which no student gets their book. We have the following possibilities:

B - $K_c$

C - $K_d$

D - $K_b$

or

B - $K_d$

C - $K_b$

D - $K_c$

Any other configuration would lead to at least one of B, C or D getting their book. Thus the $2$ in the formula, we are counting for these two possibilities. Finally, we need to account for the fact that any of A, B, C or D can be the one student who gets their book (initially we assumed A would get it). Thus, we multiply the total by ${4 \choose 1}$.

Finally, we obtain:

$$P(X=1) = \frac{{4 \choose 1} \times 2}{24}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of a famous problem. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187080/probability-that-secret-santa-arrangement-will-result-in-perfect-pairings/187104#187104) is another related Q&A.

You have one explanation. Let's explore several others.

**Tedious enumeration.** In this problem there are only $4! = 24$ arrangements of the four books to be
returned. We can make a complete list, and count how many students get their own books in each case

```
ABCD (4)  ABDC (2)  ACBD (2)  ACDB (1)  ADBC (1)  ADCB (2)
BACD (1)  BACD (0)  BCAD (1)  BCDA (0)  BDAC (0)  BDCA (1)
CABD (1)  CADB (0)  CBDA (2)  CBDA (1)  CDAB (0)  CDBA (0)
DSBC (0)  DACB (1)  DBAC (1)  DBCA (2)  DCAB (0)  DCBA (0)
```

There are 9 arrangements with none, ***8 with one,*** 6 with two, 0 with three, and 1 with all four books properly returned. So the answer is 8 out of 24, as in your formula.

**Simulation.** Another method uses simulation. In R, the `sample` function will make
random permutations of specified elements. We'll use the integers 1 through 4 to represent the four books. We can count how many are in the proper order `1 2 3 4` for each rearrangement. If we do this a million times, we can get a sufficiently close approximation to answer the question.

```
set.seed(1210)
own = replicate( 10^6, sum( sample(1:4)==1:4 ) )
mean(own==1)
[1] 0.333622       # aprx P(Exactly 1) == 8/24
24*mean(own==1)
[1] 8.006928       # aprx numerator == 8
```

If the random variable $X$ is the number of correctly returned books,
then its PDF can be approximated as follows:

```
table(own)/10^6
own
       0        1        2        4 
0.374896 0.333622 0.250025 0.041457  # aprx 9/24, 8/24, 6/24, 1/24
```

We must have $E(X) = 1.$ The probability A gets his/her own book is 1/4, and so the indicator random variable $X_1$ that takes the value 1 if Yes and 0 if No has $E(X_1) = 0(3/4) + 1(1/4) = 1/4.$ Similarly, for random variables $X_2, X_3, X_4$ that indicate proper return for the other three students. Then 
$$E(X) = E(X_1) + E(X_2) + E(X_3) + E(X_4) = 1.$$
With a somewhat more complicated argument one can show that $V(X) = 1.$

**Poisson approximation.** An interesting side comment is that $E(X) = 1, V(X) = 1$ holds no matter
how many books $n \ge 2$ are to be returned. Another kind of random variable with mean and variance both numerically equal to $1$ is
$\mathsf{Pois}(1).$ While $X$ is not Poisson, it becomes approximately Poisson for about $n > 10$ books to be returned.

```
set.seed(12)
x = replicate( 10^6, sum( sample(1:15)==1:15 ) )
mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 1.000313     # aprx E(X) = 1
[1] 1.003888     # aprx Var(X) = 1

hist(x, br=(-1:15)+.5, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  y = 0:15;  pdf = dpois(y, 1)
  points(y, pdf, col="red")
```

[image]

In the figure above the histogram bars are from the simulation of
returning 15 books, and the (centers of) the red circles are exact
Poisson probabilities. The simulated distribution is not *exactly* 
$\mathsf{Pois}(1);$ There is no possible way to return exactly 14 books out of 15 to proper owners. And of course, no way to return more than 15
books.

*Note:* The inclusion-exclusion principle of probability theory can be use used to solve the 'derangements' problem. Additionally, the page linked at the top of this Answer discusses still other methods.
And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) has a relevant article. Finally, this problem is sometimes called the 'hatcheck' problem (hats, not books, being returned); you can google that for a few dozen useful hits.